# .vimrc backupdir several directories

Tags: vim, directory, backup

I would like to create backup file in several directories after `:w` in vim, if statement is true. Vim `:help` says, that you need to put commas between directories and nothing else. But it's not working for me. It reads only the first directory. I tried different ways, such as using`set backupdir+=`, or `~/.` instead of `.`.

```
set backup
set nowritebackup
set backupdir=~/Dropbox
if expand("%")==".vimrc"
    set backupdir=.,~/.vim/backUpDir/,~/Dropbox
endif
```

In .vimrc expand returns

```
:echo expand("%")==".vimrc"
1
```

---

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4
MacOS X (unix) version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible without custom plugin. If you read the vim help carefully, it says that the backup file will be created in the *first* directory in the list where this is possible. So the behavior you are seeing is **by design**.

```
                        *'backupdir'* *'bdir'*
'backupdir' 'bdir'  string  (default for Amiga: ".,t:",
                 for MS-DOS and Win32: ".,c:/tmp,c:/temp"
                 for Unix: ".,~/tmp,~/")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    List of directories for the backup file, separated with commas.
    - The backup file will be created in the first directory in the list
      where this is possible.  The directory must exist, Vim will not
      create it for you.
```

If you really want to be able to backup to multiple directories, I would suggest writing a function to do this, and attaching it to [BufWritePre](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWrite).

Comment: Oh, I read it like about 10 times and didn't see the 'first'. Thank you

Comment: @Demyanov, No worries, it is easy to miss a single word in a sentence. :)